# Sort WPF ListView with a DataTemplate instead of DisplayMemberBinding

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, datatemplate

I am working an a sortable WPF `ListView` and I made a lot of progress already. It's not so hard since there is a lot of stuff on the internet already. But there is a little bit of information I am still missing.

With a Column like that:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="Fahrzeugname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
```

I can sort it like this:

```
Binding columnBinding = column.DisplayMemberBinding as Binding;

if (columnBinding != null)
{
    sorts.Clear();
    sorts.Add(new SortDescription(columnBinding.Path.Path, direction));
    lastColumnSorted = column;
}
```

But my problem is I don't have a `DisplayMemberBinding` since I use a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

How do I get the `Binding` property for this column in the C# Code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a set of attached properties to do exactly what Kent suggested, you can check it out [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/27/wpf-automatically-sort-a-gridview-when-a-column-header-is-clicked/)

---

EDIT : as requested, here's a sample of a command for `GridViewSort.Command` :

```
    private ICommand _sortCommand;
    public ICommand SortCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sortCommand == null)
            {
                _sortCommand = new RelayCommand(SortPersonsBy);
            }
            return _sortCommand;
        }
        set { _sortCommand = value; }
    }

    private void SortPersonsBy(object param)
    {
        string propertyName = param as string;
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_persons);
        ListSortDirection direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
        if (view.SortDescriptions.Count > 0)
        {
            SortDescription currentSort = view.SortDescriptions[0];
            if (currentSort.PropertyName == propertyName)
            {
                if (currentSort.Direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                else
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(propertyName, direction));
        }
    }
```

(it actually implements the same behavior as when `GridViewSort.AutoSort` is set to true...)

Comment: Great article! A sample for the GridViewSort.Command would be fine. Since I am not so experienced with this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you attempt to do this automatically? Why not provide an attached property that users can set to dictate the property by which the column should be sorted?

```
<GridViewColumn s:SortableColumn.SortBy="{Binding Name}" ...>
```

That way you offer more freedom of implementation, and the code will be faster and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

the WPF built-in way would be to use the ICollectionView.

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourItemsSourceList);
if(view.CanSort)
{
   view.SortDescriptions.Add(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar WPF Listview/Gridview sorting issue and I have some contraints which makes it difficult to implement the CSharp solutions provided. Essentially I have an existing ASP.NET application with thousands of lines of debugged VB code as well as working SQL for a database with over 100 tables and some very complex joins. I have to write a Windows .exe based upon the same application but I want to use WPF to implement a similar graphical look & feel.

Having finished with the disclaimer I encountered the sorting issue and searched the internet for all the great shared concepts like those above and tried converting them from CS into VB. I am an experienced programmer but I discovered that this was simply beyond my reach so I turned elsewhwere and developed my own sort instead. It will probably horrify the purists but I am a pragmatist and producing a commercial application takes precedence.

In order to sort the grid I decided to just use the Mouse events on the column headers. DoubleClick for Ascending sorts and MouseRightButtonUp for descending.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Project Name &#160;&#160;" Width="300" >

Private Sub ListViewGrid_MouseDoubleClick(
    ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles ListingDG.MouseDoubleClick

    Try
        Dim mouseHdrClick As String = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.OriginalSource, System.Object), System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock).Text
        Dim SqlOrderBy As String = ""

        Select Case UCase(mouseHdrClick.Trim)
            Case UCase("Product Name")
                SqlOrderBy = " ORDER BY Product_Name"
```

Then I just reload the ListViewGrid using the SqlOrderBy string variable. The only problem I encountered was that I was forced to click on the Header text in the column header for it to work. I solved that by just appending the XML space character (`&#160;`) to fill the column width. The `.Trim` command clears them off again for the Select Case to work. I still haven't figured out how to add the little Up and Down arrows but the functionality is what counts here since those are just cosmetic touches right now.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Project Name &#160;&#160;" Width="300">
```

Finally let me add that I am fully aware that if I change the Gridview structure it will cause the Header text to move elsewhere in the OriginalSource but that is an issue I can live with for now. I know that this is a quick & dirty workaround and there are probably much better alternatives so any recommendations will be appreciated.